# Cannot view updated data of MS Access table in data grid view using Visual Basic 2008 runtime

Tags: forms, visual-studio-2008, datagridview, load, ms-access-2007

I cannot view the updated data of an MS Access table in data grid view.  I am using the Visual Basic 2008 runtime.

```
Private Sub Form5_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim dt As New DataTable

    cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\Project\myproject.accdb"
    cn.Open()

    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT [c_id], c_name, c_address, c_no " & _
                                    "FROM customer ORDER BY [c_id]", cn)
    da.Fill(dt)

    Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

    cn.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Please edit your question to be more specific. What do you mean when you say that you "cannot view the *updated* data"? Can you see any data at all? Do you get an error? Also, what do you mean by "the Visual Basic 2008 *runtime*"? (For what it's worth, I don't see any obvious errors in your code.)

Comment: I have two forms in one form i fill customer detail which gets updated in customer table that is visible in datagrid view but only when i stop debugging my application and start again not at the time i insert details and go back to the form having gridview .

Answer (score 0):

Your DataTable is currently being filled in the `_Load` event of the form so that only happens once, when the form first loads. In order to see any changes to the data (e.g., as applied directly to the database table via your other form) you will need to refresh the contents of the DataTable.

One way to do that would be to move the `da.Fill(dt)` statement to the `Form5_Activate` event handler. That way the DataTable will get refilled when the form is reactivated.